# what is the purpose of using of "$_SESSION['authuser'] = 1" in php, why we use 1 in this section

Tags: php, session

actually, i could not understand why do we use "$_SESSION['authuser'] = 1;" in php code, my code as below

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];
$_SESSION['userpass'] = $_POST['pass'];
$_SESSION['authuser'] = 1;
//Check username and password information

if(($_SESSION['username'] == 'joe') and
($_SESSION['userpass'] == '123')) {
$_SESSION['authuser'] = 1;
} 
else 
{
echo 'Sorry, but you don\'t have permission to view this page!';
exit();
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because session (and cookie) support needs it due to a many reasons.

Ie, otherwise it would be required for you (and your visitors) to enter username and password every single time when you CLICK on an any link of your page.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['user'];
    $_SESSION['userpass'] = $_POST['pass'];
    $_SESSION['authuser'] = 0; // user is not authenticated (just a GUEST), default is 0...


// if visitor is priviledged, show him in, let him see the page

    if(($_SESSION['username'] == 'joe') and
    ($_SESSION['userpass'] == '123')) {
    $_SESSION['authuser'] = 1;  // insert 1 into DB and set cookie as 1 for user not to enter username and pswd anymore during browsing
    } 
    else 
    {
//else, keep guest away from a page
    echo 'Sorry, but you don\'t have permission to view this page!';
    exit(); // shut down 
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the usage of SESSION for username and userpass seems to be redundant. This could be possible.

```
<?php
session_start();
/*Do not set sessions for username and userpass, only use them in the POST array
 *Initialize authuser to 0 because by default a user is not logged in
 */
$_SESSION['authuser'] = 0;
//Check username and password information
if(($_POST['user'] == 'joe') and
  ($_POST['pass'] == '123')) { //Check the user and set it as authenticated
    $_SESSION['authuser'] = 1;
} else { //If the user is not valid, stop execution
    echo 'Sorry, but you don\'t have permission to view this page!';
    exit();
}
?>
```

What I'm doing here is:

- Starting session
- Initializing user as not authenticated (this is optional)
- Checking username and password

  - If they are valid, setting user as authenticated
  - If not, stopping execution.

Note that it could be useful to set a session for username and password once user is authenticated, instead of only remember the user is logged.